# Loading function files in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I am new to Scilab, but I do have MatLab and Octave experience. I'm just starting to write custom functions and when I try to load them into Scilab, I get the following error.

```
!--error 10000 
listvarinfile: Wrong variable type (1.686D+08) found in '<pathname>\test.sci'. File may be wrong or corrupted.
at line      50 of function listvarFunction called by :  
at line      29 of function listvarinfile called by :  
at line     949 of function %_sodload called by :  
<pathname>\test.sci'
```

In this case the test file was pretty simple:

```
function [x]=test(y)

x = y*y;

endfunction
```

saved with the .sci extension.

The function was loaded from the IDE by right clicking on the file and choosing the Load into Scilab option.

I had more complex examples but decided to write this since they were not loading either.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, it seems that I should have exec function_name rather than load, at least this worked.  I found the description load(function_name) or load function_name on another blog.  Perhaps I've used it incorrectly or it's old info.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Matlab,  in scilab you need run the function.

Just run the function first and then call it in the console .

test(4)

ans  =

```
16.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as user2240469 said, but you can do this in the console. See also [the documentation of exec](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/exec.html).

```
 // Use -1 as mode to prevent printing everything in the console
 -->exec('test.sci',-1)

 -->test(4)

 ans = 

 16.
```